Convergence to a continuous distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$ implies uniform convergence

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a continuous distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and
let $\{\mathcal{D}_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of distributions
converging to $\mathcal{D}$ in the following sense:
$\forall$ circle $C \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, and $\forall \epsilon > 0$,
there $\exists n_C$ , so that $\forall n \geq n_C$ , it holds that
$\lVert\mathcal{D}(C) − \mathcal{D}_n(C)\rVert\leq \epsilon$.
Show that in fact:
$\forall \epsilon > 0$, there $\exists n_\epsilon$ so that $\forall n > n_\epsilon$, and $\forall$ circles $C \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, it holds that $\lVert\mathcal{D}(C) − \mathcal{D}_n(C)\rVert\leq\epsilon$.


What I tried:
I didn't get very far with this question, but I do have some observations that I am trying to put together.

While the notation $\mathcal{D}$ doesn't seem to be well defined, I assume that the PDF of the distribution is given to be continuous, and that $\mathcal{D}(C)$ refers to the CDF.
The real image $\mathcal{D}(C)$ is in $[0,1]$, which is compact/sequentially compact.
The CDF is uniformly continuous along each axis by monotone convergence theorem.

I think the solution has something to do with sequential compactness, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.
Is there something I'm missing?

Looking into it further, I wonder if this could be shown similarly to the proof of Glivenko-Cantelli theorem...
